# Power BI: Combine multiple measures in a single matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Example:

I have a product table:

[image]

On this table I have 4 measures:

```
1) Lowest Sales Price = MIN([Sales price])
2) Highest Sales Price = MAX([Sales price])
3) Lowest Cost Price = MIN([Cost price])
4) Highest Cost Price = MAX([Cost price])
```

I want to see the results in one single matrix:

[image]

I'm struggling with finding a way to accomplish this. I guess it can be done with DAX table functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an auxiliary table, to create the distinction of `Lowest` and `Highest`.

Here are the steps:

## Step 1

Create a table containing Highest and Lowest values. I recommend also including an ID column to sort those two values as you wish. I've named the table `DimType`.

### DAX: Create table

```
DimType =
DATATABLE (
    "Id", INTEGER,
    "Type", STRING,
    {
        { 1, "Lowest" },
        { 2, "Highest" }
    }
)
```

### DimType

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lowest |
| 2 | Highest |

## Step 2

Create a calculation that uses the created table to differentiate between `Lowest` and `Highest`

### DAX: Sales

```
Sales =
SWITCH (
    ISFILTERED ( DimType[Type] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DimType[Type] ) = "Lowest", MIN ( 'Product'[Sales Price] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DimType[Type] ) = "Highest", MAX ( 'Product'[Sales Price] )
)
```

### DAX: Cost

```
Cost =
SWITCH (
    ISFILTERED ( DimType[Type] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DimType[Type] ) = "Lowest", MIN ( 'Product'[Cost Price] ),
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DimType[Type] ) = "Highest", MAX ( 'Product'[Cost Price] )
)
```

## Step 3

To show the metrics as rows, you can only use a matrix. On the `Format` pane, in `Values` enable `Show on rows`.

[image]

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The matrix doesn't work this way. The row and column attributes should be values in columns, while in your case `Sales price` and `Cost price` are not values, but columns. You can transform your data a bit to get this result. Open Power Query Editor, select `Sales price` and `Cost price` columns and click `Unpivot Columns` button in the ribbon:

[image]

This will convert these columns into values:

[image]

Then create these measures:

`Highest`:

```
Highest = MAX('Table'[Value])
```

And `Lowest`:

```
Lowest = MIN('Table'[Value])
```

And use them as values in the matrix as follows:

[image]